# Trying to scrape text from finance.yahoo.com using scrapy but all i get is an empty list

Tags: scrapy

I opened a scrapy shell to finance.yahoo.com using the command `scrapy shell http://finance.yahoo.com`

i use xpath extension for chrome to copy the xpath of the element. It is the "Stock Watch" word highlighted in yellow on top of the page

then i used the command `response.xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_18_1_1_1440609738592_1798"]').extract()`

what i am expecting is the word "stock watch" to be returned. But instead all i get is []

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is because there is no `id` attribute in the response you get.

You can verify this with the following code:

```
In [20]: response.xpath('//div/span/..').extract()[0]
Out[20]: u'<div class="hd"> <span>Stock watch:</span> </div>'
```

And by the way: the ID you see in your browser differs every time and on every machine you call up the finance site -- those ids are generated automatically when the site loads.